# c# Confusion over what type of array and usage

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am new to c# and am trying to build an array of arrays of items. I have looked at 2d arrays and jagged arrays and simply can't work out what i'm supposed to be using and can not get it to work. It's not so much building the array it's then looping through it to interrogate the array elements. I'm working within an existing library which is where all the variables come from, most of the other supporting code I've left out as it's not relevant. Once a instance is found i'm then trying to update a field from 0 to 1. Many thanks for any help in advance.

```
//Declare array
private double[,] myOpenTrades;

private void mymethod  (double score, double RSIComboScore, int type, int line)
{

myOpenTrades[line,0] = type;
myOpenTrades[line,1] = CurrentBar;
myOpenTrades[line,2] = Close[0];
myOpenTrades[line,3] = rewardClose;
myOpenTrades[line,4] = riskClose;
myOpenTrades[line,5] = score;
myOpenTrades[line,6] = RSIComboScore;
myOpenTrades[line,7] = this.getSMATrend();
myOpenTrades[line,8] = Math.Round(NSRSICS(5, 15, 60, 240).Rsi200AVGPlot[0]);
myOpenTrades[line,9] = myReward;
myOpenTrades[line,10] = myRisk;
myOpenTrades[line,11] = 0;
```

}

```
protected override void OnMyChange()
        {
            foreach(double[] row in myOpenTrades)
            {
                if(Close[0] >= row[3] && row[11]==0)
                {
                    Print("WIN:"+row[10]);
                    row[11]=1;
                }
                else if(Close[0] >= row[4] && row[11]==0)
                {
                    Print("LOSE:"+row[9]);
                    row[11]=1;
                }
            }
{
```

Comment: Should add I come from a php background which I think is causing some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this is being downvoted, it seems like a legitimate question from a new user who made some effort.

To answer your question, an array of arrays is not the best choice, because from a logical organization perspective you don't have a "grid" (i.e. 2D array) of the same item, you have multiple items as one record, and an array of records. Not to mention that you appear to be trying to mix and match types; your array is declared as `double` but the first record `type` is an integer.

I would recommend using a `class` as follows:

```
class OpenTrades
{
    public int Type;
    public Bar CurrentBar;
    public double Score;
    // etc...
}
```

(This is assume that `CurrentBar`'s type is `Bar`; you'll have to substitute `Bar` with whatever that type actually is.)

Then you would instantiate an array of your class like this:

```
OpenTrades[] myOpenTrades = new OpenTrades[11];    // This will create an array of 11 elements, indices 0 to 10
```

Now in your `mymethod` function you can assign values to each of your members.

```
myOpenTrades[line].Type = type;
myOpenTrades[line].Bar = CurrentBar;
myOpenTrades[line].Score = score;
// etc ...
```

Comment: Hi @reticulated-Spline. Many thanks for your reply and yes I had had a good go at it before turning to here. My only confusion now how i get the stuff out to play with it. What you've done seems to work, no errors, but soon as I try to access it I get an error "myOpenTrades does no exist in the current context" I'm wondering whether lists might be a better option.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with whether you use an array or a list. An array is when you have a collection of a known size, and a list is for when you have a collection whose size can change dynamically at run-time. The error message is because you're trying to access `myOpenTrades` out of scope. Edit your original post and add the code you have now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response it helped me to work out that it was in fact lists that I needed to be using and have now implemented successfully.